# QDockWidget Tab Position

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, tabs, qdockwidget

When I group multiple QDockWidgets in the same place, their tabs go at the bottom.  Is there a way to put them at the top?

Even better is if I can replace the title bar with the tabs themselves.  the Eclipse IDE has very similar behavior, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: Eclipse Tabs].

For example, the JUnit tab is also it's header and can be dragged to dock it anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control where the tabs are in each of the dock areas with [`QMainWindow::setTabPosition`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setTabPosition).

Comment: Thanks.  I moved the question about dragging tabs to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099917/qdockwidget-draggable-tabs