# Qt Designer & Dock Widgets

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget

Is there a way to initialize two dock widgets as being tabbed using the Qt Designer? I know this is possible with the API in the C++ directly; however, I would like to edit two or more dockable widgets within the designer and have them be tabbed to start. When I dock both widgets to the bottom dock they are sitting side by side and not one on top of the other. I can open preview and drag them to be tabbed, but they do not start this way.

Also, any idea when they are tabbed to make the tab bar appear on the top of the group and not the bottom?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: You can use the function tabifyDockWidget() inside your program to stack two widgets, even if they have been defined inside Qt-designer

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the first question seems to be: no that is not possible. Would be a great thing to have though.

For you second answer, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099917/qdockwidget-draggable-tabs).